# Lambda in C++0x: error: conversion from to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I've faced with problem while compiling lambda-function:

```
... (int level = 3) ...
QString str = [level] {QString s;for(int i=0;i++<level;s.append(" "));return s;};
```

Content of the error:

```
error: conversion from 'GainStatistic::getWidgetAndProps(QObject*, int)::<lambda()>' to non-scalar type 'QString' requested
```

I've tried this variant:

```
... (int level = 3) ...
QString str ([level] {QString s;for(int i=0;i++<level;s.append(" "));return s;});

error: no matching function for call to 'QString::QString(GainStatistic::getWidgetAndProps(QObject*, int)::<lambda()>)'
```

But lambda-expression in a function is simply value of some type? Is that right? Thus, `QString(lambda-that-returns-QString)` must call the `QString::QString(const QString& ref)` constructor and this must work:

```
... (int level = 3) ...
QString str([level] {const QString& ref = "123";return ref;}); //leads to the same error
```

Another variant:

```
QString str = [level]->QString {QString s;for(int i=0;i++<level;s.append(" "));return s;};

error: expected token ';' got 'str'
```

MinGW 4.6.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You try to assign a lambda to a `QString`. What do you expect to happen? A lambda taking no arguments is a nullary function. You need to call it to get its return value.

e.g.

```
int x = [] { return 23; }();
                         ^^
                        call
```

Also, thanks for showing me the syntax for a no-argument lambda. I didn't know this was possible. I'm also a little unsure if it is really legal.

**Edit:** It is legal. 5.1.2

```
lambda-expression:
    lambda-introducer lambda-declarator{opt} compound-statement

lambda-declarator:
    (parameter-declaration-clause) mutable{opt}
```

Comment: It is legal. In `5.1.2.4`: "If a lambda-expression does not include a lambda-declarator, it is as if the lambda-declarator were ()".

Comment: Think it is legal, `int main() { auto f = [] { return 23; }; return f(); }`

Comment: @jrok Thanks. I just confirmed that as well and added the relevant grammar productions.

Comment: Thank you @pmr! I forgot about ()

Answer (score 2):

Lambda's are anonymous functions with the basic structure `[capture](arguments){code}`. You don't pass an argument to your lambda. I think you want

```
QString str = [](int x){QString s;for(int i=0;i++<x;s.append(" "));return s;} (level);
//            ^^ lambda starts here                         argument to lambda ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

From C++11 standard, 5.1.2.2 (shortened by me)

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type - called the *closure type* - whose properties are described below. [More text follows]

So, what others said, `QString` and the type of the lambda are incompatible.